# Create PHP Array From MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

The output from the mysql db query is like this (example):

```
type   count   amount
----   -----   ------
A      1       100
B      2       200
C      3       300
```

and so on... that is saved in a php variable called `$data`

From this result, I want to loop through the result and create a php array that will output json like this:

```
{
    "types": [
           { 
            "type": "A",
            "count": 1,
            "amount": 100
           }
           { 
            "type": "B",
            "count": 2,
            "amount": 200
           }
           { 
            "type": "C",
            "count": 3,
            "amount": 300
           }
      ]
}
```

What I have done so far ... I am able to loop through them like this:

```
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
 echo $v->type;
 echo $v->count;
 echo $v->amount;    
}
```

How do I create a php array with this? I know how to convert to JSON but I need help in writing the loop that will create the array in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted, you already have an array of objects. From that you can simply create the parent object and assign the data to it:

```
// json_encode will create JSON objects for PHP arrays with string keys.
$parent = ['types'=>$data];
echo json_encode($parent, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thank you for the very simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you get data into the `$data` variable, you can construct a new array this way:

```
$array = ['types' => []];

foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
   $array['types'][] = [
       'type' => $v->type,
       'count' => $v->count,
       'amount' => $v->amount
   ];
}

echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: That all seems a bit involved since the OP starts with an array. He can just assign it to an element in a parent array in one line, and json_encode() it.

Comment: Yeah it's not the most efficient way of solving the problem, but the OP asked for help on how to write the loop that would help him build the array.

Comment: @JacobMulquin the way I get the result of the query into $data is get_var($query)